# Initial setup of Bitlocker making system ask for recovery key then reboots

Tags: windows, windows-10, bitlocker

First, my system is a dual boot of two windows - Window 10 Enterprise and Windows 10 Pro.

I wanted to bitlocker the system so I started in Windows on the Pro partition.  I told it to bitlocker for C: only and then told it to perform a system check first to ensure that everything was going to work right. After clicking ok it immediately wanted to restart the system in order to begin bitlocker.

After booting it comes to the OS selection screen, I click the Pro Windows and it asks for the recovery key.  I entered it but when I hit enter the system just restarts and we do it all over again.

I'm unsure why this is even happening when I know the thing has not bitlockered the drive yet.  How do I get past this?

**EDIT**: If I boot into the other Windows I see the drive as Encrypted.  When I double click it, it asks for the key.  I put it in exactly as is shown on the text file it had saved before but it says the key does not match.  Ideas?

**EDIT 2**: When I boot the system up and it gets to the enter the recovery key page, the error says "Bitlocker needs your recovery key to unlock your drive because the trusted platform module is not accessible."  It then lists the key ID - which matches what I have in the document.  I can see that the TPM is enabled in the BIOS though and in the other windows in TPM Administration it states "ready"

**EDIT 3**: Windows Version 1803. There was a question during the bitlocker setup which asked me if I wanted the new encryption or the compatible encryption - I had selected the new

**EDIT 4**: Just to check, I went through the steps on the other Windows.  The last step is the one asking for the system check and says it will restart your computer before performing the bitlocker in order to test that your TPM works.  I think (somehow) this screwed up the partition cause it now thinks the data is encrypted - even though it's not - but the key is somehow applied. I may try mounting the drive with a Linux LiveCD to see if I can mount the NTFS partition and see the data on it or something.

Comment: Did you interrupt the encrypting process before it was finished?  If you enabled BitLocker on a specific partition, then the process to encrypt that partition, should have began immediately.

Comment: Which version of Windows 10 are you using on each partition?  Windows 10 Version 1511 introduced a new encryption mode, which was NOT backward compatible, with earlier editions of Windows.

Comment: You failed to indicate your the TPM error, within the firmware, do you have the TPM enabled?  Let us only worry about the installation, for the purposes of this question, that you enabled BitLocker on.

Comment: Please think of my wrist health, and edit your question, instead of submitting comments.

Comment: Is there anything additional learned about this scenario?  Did you recover in some way?

Comment: No.  Unfortunately @Mafu-Josh there was no way to recover the data.  I don't know what happened but I know I had to format the entire drive and just re-install.  Ive re-configured bitlocker two times on different machines since then and both times when it asks to reset the computer to do the TPM check and I tell it no. I've had no other problems. All I can say is make a backup before you bitlocker!